# PHP - What is the difference between “instantiated” and “initialised”?

Tags: php, variables, object

I'm reading few books about PHP and getting stared to grab the basics. I came across “instantiated” and “initialised” words. I can not find an example which explains them.

What is the difference between “instantiated” and “initialised” in PHP ? What do they mean ? How to use them ? What's the purpose of using them ?

Provide an example if possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You `instantiate` an object from a class. I.e. you create an `instance` (hence the name). In code:

```
$obj = new SomeClass();
```

You `initialise` a variable, which means "giving it its initial (hence the name) value".

```
$var = "someValue";
```

In fact, when you `instantiate`, you also often `initialise` it (in the constructor). For example:

```
// this instantiates an object of class 'SomeClass' and 
// initialises it with "somevalue"
$obj = new SomeClass("someValue");
```

Instantiation is a object-oriented programming term. Initialisation is used in all languages. Both terms are certainly not limited to PHP.

Answer (score 2):

1. Instances are where you have allocated memory for the variable but may or may not have placed a value in there.
2. Initialized is where you have allocated memory as well as stored an intial value to it as well.

Just adding after reading Barts Answer that object oriented programming usually refers to instances in terms of objects being allocated memory while variables are said to be initialised which means allocated memory and assigned a value as well.

So for example

```
int $intarray=new Array(); // Instance created
```

while

```
int $intarray= new Array({1,2,3}); // instance created and initialised
```

Answer (score 2):

When you define a class in any object oriented programming language, you create a blue print of an object but the object does not exist. But when you create a copy of that object based on the class or blue print defined, you actually instantiate a class. For example:

//Define a Class called Foo

```
class Foo {
    public $aMemberVar = 'aMemberVar Member Variable';
    public $aFuncName = 'aMemberFunc';


    function aMemberFunc() {
        print 'Inside `aMemberFunc()`';
    }
}
```

// Create an object of type Foo * Instantiate Foo

```
$foo = new Foo;
```

Now for Initialised, consider any variable. When you declare a variable, it is there but does not hold any meaningful value. So, the process of assigning a value for the first time to a variable is known as intialisation. Initialisation may happen at the time you declare a variable or may be later programmatically.

Just declare a variable:

```
var $newVariable;
```

Intialise the above variable:

```
$newVariable = "This is intialisation";
```

Declare and intialise a variable:

```
var $intialisedVar = "This var is declared and intialised";
```

Just to add another point in intialisation, see the variables in the class above. These variables will be intialised automatically as soon as you instantiated an object.

Hope this helps.